# Making Django admin display the Primary Key rather than each object's Object type

Tags: python, django, admin

In Django 1.1 admin, when I go to add or change an object, my objects are displayed as:

```
Select host to change
    * Add host

    Host object
    Host object
    Host object
    Host object
    Host object
```

This happens for all models in my site, not just Hosts.

Rather than display the same name for each object, I would like Django to display the primary key.

```
Select host to change
    * Add host

    machine1
    machine2
```

Here is my code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Host(models.Model):
    host = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    class Admin:
        list_display = ('host')


class Test(models.Model):
    testname = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    class Admin:
        list_display = ('testname')

class Result(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(Host)
    TESTRESULT_CHOICES = (
        ('P', 'Pass'),
        ('F', 'Fail'),
    )
    testresult = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TESTRESULT_CHOICES)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    testname = models.OneToOneField(Test, primary_key=True)
    class Admin:
        list_display = ('host','testname','time','testresult','reason')
```

Reading http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/:

"ModelAdmin.list_display

Set list_display to control which fields are displayed on the change list page of the admin."

However this simply does not seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 33):

Add a [`__unicode__()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__unicode__) method to `Host`. To show the primary key of your host objects, you'd want something like:

```
class Host(models.Model):
    host = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.pk

    ...
```

You might want to think about showing the contents of the `host` field:

```
class Host(models.Model):
    host = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.host

    ...
```

You'll need to do something similar for every model you've got.

For Python 3 compatibility, you'll want to do something like this (see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods)):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Host(models.Model):
    host = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.host

    ...
```

Answer (score 10):

`contrib.admin` has been reworked in 1.0, and old `Admin` classes inside models no longer work. What you need is `ModelAdmin` subclass in `your_application.admin` module, e.g.

```
from your_application.models import Host
from django.contrib import admin

class HostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('host',)

admin.site.register(Host, HostAdmin)
```

Or use `__unicode__` in the model itself, e.g.

```
class Host(models.Model):
    host = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.host
```

Answer (score 3):

It might also be worth mentioning that, if you are using an auto-incrementing primary key for your models, you will need to coerce it into a string, eg:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.pk)
```