# Object type instead of specific value from def __unicode__ showed in admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-unicode

According to [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336463/django-xxxxxx-object-display-customization-in-admin-action-sidebar) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594436/making-django-admin-display-the-primary-key-rather-than-each-objects-object-typ) I made model which is listed in another model as `kierunek = models.ForeignKey('Kierunek', default=1)` and as name of select, show `self.nazwa_kierunku`. Everything works fine, but I cant get `def __unicode__` works. I tried also `def __str__`. There is always name "Object Kierunek".

One of my code samples. I tried many variants of this:

```
from django.db import models

class Kierunek(models.Model):
    nazwa_kierunku = models.CharField('Nazwa kierunku', max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Timecreated', auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField('Timeupdated', auto_now=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nazwa_kierunku

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Nazwa kierunku"
    verbose_name_plural = "Nazwy kierunkow"
```

Comment: there is no `unicode` type in Python 3, so there is no `__unicode__` magic method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using pyhton 3

```
__str__() and  __unicode__() methods
```

> In Python 2, the object model specifies **str**() and  **unicode**()
>   methods. If these methods exist, they must return str (bytes) and
>   unicode (text) respectively.
>
> The print statement and the str built-in call **str**() to determine
>   the human-readable representation of an object. The unicode built-in
>   calls  **unicode**() if it exists, and otherwise falls back to
>   **str**() and decodes the result with the system encoding. Conversely, the Model base class automatically derives **str**() from 
>   **unicode**() by encoding to UTF-8.
>
> In Python 3, there’s simply **str**(), which must return str (text).
>
> (It is also possible to define **bytes**(), but Django application
>   have little use for that method, because they hardly ever deal with
>   bytes.)
>
> Django provides a simple way to define **str**() and  **unicode**()
>   methods that work on Python 2 and 3: you must define a **str**()
>   method returning text and to apply the python_2_unicode_compatible()
>   decorator.
>
> On Python 3, the decorator is a no-op. On Python 2, it defines
>   appropriate  **unicode**() and **str**() methods (replacing the
>   original **str**() method in the process). Here’s an example:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class MyClass(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "Instance of my class"
```

> This technique is the best match for Django’s porting philosophy.
>
> For forwards compatibility, this decorator is available as of Django
>   1.4.2.
>
> Finally, note that **repr**() must return a str on all versions of
>   Python.

Source https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods